# Harvesting energy from a truck

Tags: solar-cell, generator, dynamo

I'm trying to create this prototype where I will require constant charging power for a sensor i will install on a trailer (container truck trailer). However, due to some problem, I wasn't able to tap power from the truck's own battery power.

Hence, I'm actually thinking of an solution where I will install a separate independent charging source to charge my sensor. For example, it could be a solar panel. However, solar panel is not optimal because some times the trailer might be indoors. I am thus wondering if there are any other ways to generate energy, such as a dynamo or alternator etc. I'm open to any ideas!

Comment: "due to some problem" - what problem? Drawing power from the vehicle's existing supply is the logical choice. You should have a good reason for making things complicated and trying something else.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to tap power? the brake lights are always on, when connected

Answer (score 1):

Yes the trailer must have power for the lights...
they wont be on when it is parked but maybe you can tap into that circuit (tail lights) and use it to charge a battery to supply your device.